# How to handle documents larger than 512 KB?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, nosql

In our application, around 10% of our data results in documents larger than 512 KB. Rest of our data results in documents that are few KBs.
We are wondering how to handle this in our code. We could split the documents, but the query becomes difficult in that case.

Will the DocumetnDb support documents larger than 512 KB anytime soon?

Comment: The product team can't comment on future plans regarding document size, or anything else that hasn't been publicly announced (note: I'm not on the product team). That said: You should edit your question to provide more details about the document design you're using, to explain why/how you are exceeding 512K.

Comment: Can you put the large documents in blob storage and put the meta-data to search for it in a DocumentDB document with an attachment that links to the blob?

Comment: I'd suggest you vote for large documents on user voice - https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-documentdb/suggestions/12809604-support-documents-larger-than-512-kb I have it on good authority the product team monitors that quite closely and uses that to prioritize requests from customers. (disclaimer: I am on the product team)

Answer (score 0):

Azure Cosmos DB supports documents up to 2 MB in size.